# D3 Responsive chart

Tags: svg, d3.js, resize, data-visualization, responsive

I want to create a responsive chart in D3.js without using viewBox. I want to avoid it because I had some problems when I added tooltips to the chart. I started with a great [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jF1XPXqom_c&list=LL&index=3&t=1s), but I cant continue following the same logic.
Anyone can help me why is it not drawing both of the lines (const axis, absAxis)? I tried to join/append to the svg, to the rect, but did not work.

```js
function myResponsiveChart(container, props) {

const  { width, height } = props;

let svg = container.selectAll('svg').data([null]);
    svg = svg.enter().append('svg').merge(svg)
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

const rect = svg.selectAll('rect').data([null]);
    rect.enter().append('rect').merge(rect)
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('rx', 100);

  const fontSize = 16,
      hPix = height/6,
      margin = { top: hPix/2, bottom: hPix/2, left: hPix/10, right: hPix/2 };


//DELTA
//svg.append('line').merge(svg)
const axis = svg.selectAll('line').data([null]);
      axis.join('line').append('line').merge(axis) 
        .attr("x1", margin.left)
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y1", margin.top)
        .attr("y2", margin.top)
        .attr("class", "diff_axis");

let axis = svg.select('line').data([null]);
  axis.enter().append('line').merge(axis) 
    .attr("x1", margin.left)
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y1", margin.top)
    .attr("y2", margin.top)
    .attr("class", "diff_axis");

//ABSOLUTE
//svg.append('line').merge(svg)
let absAxis = svg.selectAll('line').data([null]);
  absAxis.enter().append('line').merge(absAxis) 
    .attr("x1", margin.left)
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y1", margin.top + hPix)
    .attr("y2", margin.top + hPix)
    .attr("class", "diff_axis")
    .attr("id", "abs");
}

function render() {

    myResponsiveChart(d3.select('body'), {
      width: document.body.clientWidth,
      height: document.body.clientHeight
  });
}

render();
window.addEventListener('resize', render);
```

```css
body {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
  }

.diff_axis {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

**strong text**

Comment: I know you said no ViewBox, but if the issue is the tooltip positioning, maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68237912/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-a-pie-chart/68259872?noredirect=1#comment120669658_68259872 . I know this is not what you wanted, but I believe it's the cleanest solution for responsiveness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works
When you define a constraint, you cannot redefine it or change its value.

```js
function myResponsiveChart(container, props) {

const  { width, height } = props;

let svg = container.selectAll('svg').data([null]);
    svg = svg.enter().append('svg').merge(svg)
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

const rect = svg.selectAll('rect').data([null]);
    rect.enter().append('rect').merge(rect)
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('rx', 100);

  const fontSize = 16,
      hPix = height/6,
      margin = { top: hPix/2, bottom: hPix/2, left: hPix/10, right: hPix/2 };


//DELTA
//svg.append('line').merge(svg)
const axis = svg.selectAll('line').data([null]);
      axis.join('line').append('line').merge(axis) 
        .attr("x1", margin.left)
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y1", margin.top)
        .attr("y2", margin.top)
        .attr("class", "diff_axis");

//ABSOLUTE
//svg.append('line').merge(svg)
let absAxis = svg.selectAll('line').data([null]);
  absAxis.enter().append('line').merge(absAxis) 
    .attr("x1", margin.left)
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y1", margin.top + hPix)
    .attr("y2", margin.top + hPix)
    .attr("class", "diff_axis")
    .attr("id", "abs");
}

function render() {

    myResponsiveChart(d3.select('body'), {
      width: document.body.clientWidth,
      height: document.body.clientHeight
  });
}

render();
window.addEventListener('resize', render);
```

```css
body {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
  }

.diff_axis {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```